# asp.net user control, getting htmlAnchor resolve to href="#"

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

How do you get a server control HTMLAnchor to have href="#".  It keeps resolving the "#" to the control path.

```
<a href="#" runat="server" />
resolves to: <a href="../ControlPath/#">
```

I can't seem to get a google search to give me the results i want so i figured i'd ask here.

EDIT: Syntax.

Removing the runat server is not an option.  It's manipulated in the backend, this was just a simplification.

Comment: Shouldn't this be titled, "simple Asp.Net question"?

Comment: No, it should be titled something like "How can I create an HTML Anchor with href='#'?"  "simple Asp.Net question" is more correct, but just as useless in a search.

Comment: changed title as per request/point.

Comment: Easy +1 for proactively trying to improve question quality.

Comment: I've tried adding the 'href' attribute in the code behind but it still resolved to the control path.

Comment: Why are you trying to get just a "#" character?  Can a do-nothing filler like what ChaosPandion is suggestion do the trick, or do you really need just a "#" for some reason?

Comment: Mostly just an issue of best practices as attributes are added server side to the anchor tag. specifically the 'onclick' is added.  I could alter the onclick to follow a <a href="javascript:myFunction()"> and will in the event i've no other options but would rather avoid it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior, what does your markup look like and how are you adding your control to your form?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem, here's how I could resolve it:

**Original code**

User control:

```
<a id="foo" runat="server">...</a>
```

Code behind:

```
foo.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
```

Output:

```
<a id="..." href="../Shared/Controls/#">...</a>
```

**Updated code**

User control:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="foo" runat="server">...</asp:HyperLink>
```

Code behind:

```
foo.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
```

Output:

```
<a id="..." href="#">...</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  This problem was driving me nuts

Comment: This is a much preferable solution to the ones above, but is quite a way down the page!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue when rendering the page with PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance() or when the url was rewritten. For some reason the HtmlAnchor always resolved incorrectly (similar to what you have above).

Ended up just using a HtmlGenericControl, since you are manipulating it server-side anyway this may be a possibility for you.

```
HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
```

Comment: The URL rewriting is caused by the method ResolveURL on the Control class. I looked at it in Reflector and found that it will attempt to rewrite anything that it thinks is a relative URL if AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory is non-empty. The simple workaround is to set this variable on the Page object to an empty string at some global level (or at least before Render). I suppose a true fix would be to get microsoft to make UrlPath.IsRelativeUrl() smarter.

Comment: The solution of Ramses is much cleaner because there is a specific control for links in asp.net. Why use a generic one?

Comment: @Sorpigal, your solution is the best by far. I don't need someone else to translate all relative paths to what they think it is correct for me. I know where exactly my files are. I suggest posting your solution as answer to get more publicity.

Comment: @AaA: On consideration I think you're probably right, so it is done as you asked.

Answer (score 3):

Brendan Kowitz solution will work, however i was not able to implement it due to the way this control is to operate.  I ended up having to hack it as per the following code in the code behind:

```
lnk.Attributes.Add("href",Page.Request.Url.ToString() + "#");
```

Where lnk is an HtmlAnchor.

The reason for this issue in the first place is the control is not in the same directory as the page, and .Net goes about "intelligently" fixing your problem for you.  The above will work, though if anyone has a better solution i'm all ears.

Answer (score 3):

Originally I had this as a comment but by request I'm adding it as an answer since nobody else has explained why the original behavior is occurring or how to directly prevent it.

The URL rewriting is caused by the method ResolveURL on the Control class. I looked at it in Reflector and found that it will attempt to rewrite anything that it thinks is a relative URL if AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory is non-empty.

The simple workaround is to set this variable on the Page object to an empty string at some global level (or at least before Render), although this could be an issue if some other bit of your control structure requires it to be empty.

I suppose a true fix would be to get Microsoft to make UrlPath.IsRelativeUrl() smarter.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing.  If you set this on page load, it will work:

```
AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "runat" attribute and wrapping what you want to link;

```
<a href="#" >Your Link Text/Image Here</a>
```

Comment: Removing the runat="server" is not an option as other attributes are changed in the backend.  This was just a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This should work.</strike>

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">text</a>
```

This should work.

```
<a href="~/#">text</a>
```

Comment: To be clear, this answer will *not* provide what is specifically asked for...(the '#' character), but may well be good enough if all the OP needs to do is have a link that "does nothing."

Comment: The Example was such to simplify the problem.  I'm just syntactically looking to follow the href="#".  The anchor tag has a few other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Includes nested paths

My test project renders the correct link for me:

```
 http://localhost:2279/WebSite1/Default.aspx#
```

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register src="control/WebUserControl2.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl2" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
          <uc1:WebUserControl2 ID="WebUserControl21" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Control:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl2" %>
<a id="A1" href="<%# URLHelper("~/#") %>" runat="server" >here</a>
```

**Control Code-Behind:**

```
protected string URLHelper(string s)
{
    return Control.ResolveUrl(s);
}
```

Comment: Control is in path  
Project/userControls/myControl.ascx  
Page is in path  
Project/CRUD/page.aspx

It was in a repeater but the functionality is the same outside the repeater

Comment: Crap, forgot about the nested path, I will test that out.

Answer (score 0):

Mine too works fine...I have a user control AnchorTag.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AnchorTag.ascx.cs" Inherits="JavascriptScroll.AnchorTag" %>
<a id="A1" href="#" runat="server" >Anchor Tag</a>
```

And I included it as :

```
<%@ Register src="AnchorTag.ascx" tagname="AnchorTag" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

.
.
.

```
<uc1:AnchorTag ID="AnchorTag1" runat="server" />
```

.
.

And it renders as expected:

```
 <a href="#" id="AnchorTag1_A1">Anchor Tag</a>
```

Please correct me if I'm doing something which is not expected...

Comment: The control is in a seperate folder.  Specifically project/UserControls/myControl.ascx.  The page is in the folder project/Crud/MyPage.aspx.  I'm able to duplicate this functionality every time.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
HtmlAnchor errorLink = new HtmlAnchor();
errorLink.InnerText = this.Message;
errorLink.HRef = errorLink.ResolveClientUrl("#" + this.FormControlId);
errorLink.Attributes["rel"] = "form_help";
```

Works for me but I'm using a Server Control in a Class Library as opposed to a User Control. I think it should work for a User Control as well.