# Using HtmlAnchor or ASP.NET HyperLink for anchor tag that navigates in-page named anchor

Tags: asp.net, anchor

I am trying to render a simple hyperlink that links to a named anchor within the page, for example:

```
<a href="#namedAnchor">scroll to down</a>

<a name="namedAnchor">down</a>
```

The problem is that when I use an ASP.NET control like `asp:HyperLink` or `HtmlAnchor`, the `href="#namedAnchor"` is rendered as `href="controls/#namedAnchor"` (where `controls` is the subdirectory where the user control containing the anchor is).  Here is the code for the control, using two types of anchor controls, which both have the same problem:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestWebApplication1.controls.Test" %>

<a href="#namedAnchor" runat="server">HtmlAnchor</a>

<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="#namedAnchor" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

The generated source looks like:

```
<a href="controls/#namedAnchor">HtmlAnchor</a>

<a href="controls/#namedAnchor">HyperLink</a>
```

I really just want:

```
<a href="#namedAnchor">HtmlAnchor</a>

<a href="#namedAnchor">HyperLink</a>
```

I am using the `HtmlAnchor` or `HyperLink` class because I want to make changes to other attributes in the code behind.  I do not want to introduce a custom web control for this requirement, as the requirement I'm pursuing is not that important enough to justify abandoning the traditional ASP.NET link controls.  It seems like I should be able to use the ASP.NET link controls to generate the desired link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net user control, getting htmlAnchor resolve to href="#"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489332/asp-net-user-control-getting-htmlanchor-resolve-to-href)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of using the NavigateUrl property, just use the href property

```
<asp:HyperLink href="#namedAnchor" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Doesn't validate: Attribute 'href' is not a valid attribute of element 'HyperLink'.

Answer (score 9):

To set the HREF property in codebehind:

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.Attributes.Add("href", "#" + doc.DocumentID.ToString());
link.Text = doc.DocumentNumber;
```

This will give you:

```
<a href="#111">blah blah</a>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for doing it in code. (Also works for HtmlAnchor class - setting the HRef property on HtmlAnchor also generates the extra "crap")

Answer (score 2):

Set it as a custom property on the link:

```
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.Attributes.Add("name", doc.DocumentID.ToString());
        link.Text = doc.DocumentNumber;
```

This will give you:

```
<a name="111">blah blah</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use **NavigateUrl** Property, which is sometimes necessary, then you can use:

```
hypID.NavigateUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri & "#MyAnchor"
```