# ASP.NET anchor tag with runat="server" acting weird

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a strange problem with the page I'm designing.  I have a link like this:

```
<a id="asel1" runat="server" href="#"><img id="isel1" runat="server" src="/Images/selbar/1.jpg" /></a>
```

And when I view source on the resulting page I get this:

```
<a href="../Cards/#" id="ctl00_ContentMainSection_CardsControl1_asel1"><img src="/Images/selbar/1.jpg" id="ctl00_ContentMainSection_CardsControl1_isel1" /></a>
```

My goal was to programmatically insert a link if it was applicable to the page in question, and leave a href="#" if it wasn't (basically a blank anchor tag).  However now it will take them to an actual link, which of course doesn't exist.

How can I make it stop doing this?

Comment: does NOT setting the href="#" work? In case of blank anchor tag no href tag will be rendered...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595113/using-htmlanchor-or-asp-net-hyperlink-for-anchor-tag-that-navigates-in-page-named ?

Answer (score 2):

How are you inserting the link? I've just tried the following:

```
<a id="asel1" runat="server" href="#">
    <img id="isel1" runat="server" src="/Images/selbar/1.jpg" />
</a>
```

If you do nothing in the code behind the link is rendered as:

```
<a href="#" id="ctl00_MainContent_asel1">
    <img src="/Images/selbar/1.jpg" id="ctl00_MainContent_isel1" />
</a>
```

and if in the Page_Load you define the href:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    asel1.HRef = "../Cards";
}
```

it will render as:

```
<a href="../Cards" id="ctl00_MainContent_asel1">
    <img src="/Images/selbar/1.jpg" id="ctl00_MainContent_isel1" />
</a>
```

which other the `id` mangling is the expected behavior.

Comment: I neglected to mention that the link is inside a user control; this may have some bearing on its behavior.  Even if I have no code-behind and just leave it as href="#" it still wants to change it to href="../Cards/#".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I too ran into the exact same problem.  In my case the anchor tag was also inside an ASCX file (user control).  I found that if I removed:

```
runat="server"
```

then the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would have replaced the href as following:

```
<a id="asel1" runat="server" onclick="return false;">
   <img id="isel1" runat="server" src="/Images/selbar/1.jpg" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the link dynamically in asp c#, right? 
you have to look there for the href and id.

in asp, `Control.ClientID` value is generated by concatenating the ID value of the control and the UniqueID value of its parent control. That explains how your id is changing. 
According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) Each part of the generated ID property is separated by the ClientIDSeparator property value. The value always returns an underscore (_).

That is why you have `id="ctl00_ContentMainSection_CardsControl1_asel1"`