# ASP.net c# make hyperlink point to page anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

```
// Post quote
GDQ.CssClass = "s comment-quote";
GDQ.ToolTip = "Quote this post";
GDQ.NavigateUrl = "#Post";
```

And on my page I have:

```
<a name="Post"></a>
```

However, this url points to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Site/Controls/#Post
```

Which is the path that the user control is in, I need it to jump to the #Post on whatever page the control exists on.

I can do:

```
GDQ.NavigateUrl = Page.Request.Url +  "#Post";
```

But the URL I am on is rewritten, which points it to the actual filename which sends a new request.  I just want it to jump on the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it fixes it: [Using HtmlAnchor or ASP.NET HyperLink for anchor tag that navigates in-page named anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595113/using-htmlanchor-or-asp-net-hyperlink-for-anchor-tag-that-navigates-in-page-named)

So, in your case:

```
GDQ.Attributes["href"] = "#Post";
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First the anchor has no name attribute</strike>, I think you wanted to write href instead of name

Comment: Would you like to reconsider your answer? http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1

Comment: The `name` attribute is still valid though - the part that needs replacing is the use of the `NavigateUrl` property.