# How to assign label text to href link dynamically in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, keyword

After I have included my database connections in the project, I want to establish a relationship between these two. If there is a keyword from the database in the text, I want to change the keywords in the text to `<a href="myKeyword.html"> myKeyword</a>`. How can I do that?

```
DataEntity.Texts.Text myTexts  = new DataEntity.Texts.
DataEntity.Keywords.Keyword myKeywords = new DataEntity.Keywords.Keyword;
```

I have two parameters
`myTexts.Text.ToString();` first parameter
`myKeywords.Keyword.ToString();` second parameter

**I want this:**

I like football (football is in myKeywords)

```
I like <a href="football.html">football<a/>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise ? Do you want the keyword as href and the text as text ? Are you using webforms ? MVC ? Can you use javascript to achieve your goals ?

Comment: This project is c# html page. Not webforms and MVC. I sholdn't use javascript.

Comment: I want to convert my keyword to link

Comment: Have you checked this solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595113/using-htmlanchor-or-asp-net-hyperlink-for-anchor-tag-that-navigates-in-page-name#10596848

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I checked this solution. This solution is not sufficient.